# How to set font size in a text field dynamically with Appcelerator?

Tags: dynamic, fonts, appcelerator

Using Alloy, I have a textfield and would like to make the font size smaller when the user enters more than 24 characters so that nothing gets cut off in the textfield.

views.xml:

```
      <TextField  id="ccHolder" class="fieldInput"  onChange="makeFontSmaller"><Label id="cvcIcon" class="fieldIcons"/>  </TextField>
```

controller.js:

```
    function makeFontSmaller(e){
      console.log("font size " + e.source.font.fontSize); //outputs "14dp"
      if (e.source.value.length > 20) {
          e.source.font.fontSize = "12dp"; //no effect
        //$.ccHolder.value.setFont("12dp"); /no effect
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works well if you only want to change the font.

```
e.source.font = {
    fontSize : 14
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED to correct the font object]

In my first answer edit, I was naively hoping that font.fontSize could be a legit property, but it is clearly not.

Then, after Prashant's comments, I tested successfully the (more verbose) solution below, which uses `applyProperties()`

```
function makeFontSmaller(e){
  if (e.source.value.length > 20) {
      e.source.applyProperties({font: {fontSize: "12dp"}}); 
  }
}
```

Comment: We can't directly applyProperties like this *font.fontSize : "12dp"*, can we?...Studio shows an error on font.fontSize

Comment: I see, thank you, I was actually concerned about that.

Comment: maybe with {font: { fontSize: "12dp"} } ... I'd try out of curiosity :) thnx again Prashant.

Comment: Just tested successfully, I'll edit the answer, not to leave buggy code around! Ty.